# How to improve this data model, schema and relations

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I used meteor, mongoDB and auto-form. I have many entity in my data model.
Academies has some students and teachers and classes. class has some students and one teacher and some grades for each students.

I design this schema:

```
Schema = {};
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    },
    family: {
        type: String,
        label: "Family"
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        label: "Address",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    },
    workAddress: {
        type: String,
        label: "WorkAddress",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Phone Number",
        optional: true
    },
    mobileNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    }

});
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object],
        // this must be optional if you also use other login services like facebook,
        // but if you use only accounts-password, then it can be required
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
//    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
//    // Option 1: Object type
//    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
//    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
//    // Example:
//    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
//    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
//    // you will fail validation in some cases.
//    roles: {
//        type: Object,
//        optional: true,
//        blackbox: true
//    }
//    // Option 2: [String] type
//    // If you are sure you will never need to use role groups, then
//    // you can specify [String] as the type
    roles: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});
//Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

Schema.Grade: {
    student: Schema.User,
class: Schema.Class,
    gradeValue: value
}

Schema.Class: {
    teacher: Schema.User,
    students: {
        type: [Schema.User]
    },
    grades: {
        type: [Schema.Grade]
    }
}

Schema.Academy: {
    name: {
        label: "academy name",
        type: String
    },
    students: {
        type: [Schema.User]
    },
    teachers: {
        type: [Schema.User]
    },
    classes: {
        type: [Schema.Class]
    }
}
```

But I think this is not the best and many repetition encountered.

I need below queries:

```
academy classes
academy students
academy teachers
students classes
students grades
student profile
class students
class teacher
class grades
teacher students
teacher classes
teacher profile
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to identify entities: `student, teacher, class, academy`

Second, identify relationships starting with the biggest:

- 1 academy has many classes (1:M)
- 1 class has many students, 1 student has many classes (M:N)
- 1 teacher has many classes (1:M) <-- assumes no teacher aides, joint-lectures, etc.

Next, the relational schema. The trick here is to minimize uses of arrays, so for every 1:M relationship, put the foreign key on the M:

- Academy: `_id, name`
- class: `_id, name, teacherId, academyId`
- teacher: "profile"
- student: "profile"

Index on all foreign keys (teacherId, academyId).

Now we don't have any duplicates, but we still have to handle the students:class relationship.

Your example of the `Grades` collection is the textbook 3NF, SQL way to it. Nothing wrong with it, it's a great solution. (just make sure to index on the foreign keys!).

Alternatively, on the student document you could have an object, each field would be a classId & each value would be the grade.

Another option would be to have a student object on the class document, and each field would be the studentId, each value would be the grade.

How you decide which one is best is access patterns. If you have a student portal where they can see their classes and grades, it makes more sense to put it on the student collection and the occasional query to get a class average would be more expensive since it'll have to iterate through all the students. The inverse is true for nesting in the class collection.